# Mouse heatmap for django site

Tags: jquery, django

I m looking for a open source mouse tracking heatmap for website usability in django and jquery.I came across [django-mousechaser](http://github.com/dvanliere/django-mousechaser) but it is still in alpha phase.Is anyone used it or is it good to use? Please suggest any other good alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

[Gheat](https://github.com/robertrv/django-gheat) seems to be pretty popular.

Comment: i want to capture the way users are navigate through my site.